# Newline in text, ASP.NET Blazor Razor pages

Tags: c#, blazor, razor-pages

There is some text coming from a database and it showed on the Blazor Razor page as plain text. On the Razor page have set it to something like this:

```
 <p class="footText">
     @NewLine
 </p>
```

For the more readable text, I want to add a new line to each line if there is some ordered list in it, starting with a dash sign, but what I tried with `Enviroment.Newline`, and also with the ideas coming from this site, it doesn't work.
I See when debugging in this case "NewLine" that within the Text Visualizer there was added \r\n between the lines but it's still showing like plain text.
Why isn't this working and does someone have some other idea?

```
public class OrderedListText
{
    public string NewLine { get; set; }

    public string ReturnOrderedText(string strText)
    {
        string lineText;

        if (strText != null)
        {
            string[] lines = strText.Split(".");

            if (lines != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    lineText = lines[i];
                    if (lineText.StartsWith(" -"))
                    {

                        NewLine += lineText + Environment.NewLine;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return NewLine;
    }
}
```

Have tried different ideas coming from StackOverflow when searching for it.

Comment: Thanks for some solution. 
The pre tag sets newline so that's positive, but  some line will now somewhere in the middle of the line set to a new line. Very strange. 
The @(MarkupString(Newline)) gives me an error. Cannot be used like an method.  But have no knowlegde about this markup. I will search first to that how to use.

Comment: I've deleted the comment and added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS.  Note I've used `StringBuilder` to build out the text block: doing `NewLine += lineText + Environment.NewLine;` is a very expensive operation.

Here's a demo page.

The `white-space: pre-wrap;` is the important bit.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="my-text-format">
    @MyText()
</div>

// This should be added to a component css file
// in this case that would be Home.razor.css
<style>
    .my-text-format 
    {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        width: 100%;
        padding: .5em;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        background: #efefef;
        border: 1px solid #777;
    }
</style>

@code{
    // Uses StringBuilder to build out the text
    private string MyText()
    {
            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Hello");
            sb.AppendLine("Blazor");
            return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: See also [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) documentation to check the various values available for `white-space`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option here in my opinion is to split the text by `Environment.NewLine` and then render each part separately in your markup.

**Markup**

```html
@foreach (string line in MyTextLines)
{
  <div>
    @line
  </div>
}
```

**Code**

```cs
private string MyText {get; set;} = ""
private string[] MyTextLines => MyText.Split(Environment.NewLine);

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
  // TODO: fetch text from database
  MyText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,new[]
  {
    "First", "Second", "Third"
  });
}
```

Note: I have only demonstrated an approach to render newline-separated plain text as HTML. You would need to make a little extra effort to process your text in such a way that you can parse it into unordered lists and other elements.

At that point you're just rewriting markdown, so maybe consider an alternative approach if you have more complex requirements.

Example fiddle: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/f8y8jl00

**Alernative**

An alternative approach is to replace the new lines with `<br>` strings and then use `MarkupString` to render as HTML, but I would avoid this as it is an unnecessary security risk - unless you are storing HTML in the database.

Comment: Thx all for giving me some ideas. Have no tried the solution with the StringBuilder and thatl's working for me, but also will try the solution like Kurt said.
So many thanks!

Comment: This can probably be done more efficiently by using a StringReader to write each line directly to the response, followed by a <br/>.